# ActionBarSherlock app icon in wrong position

Tags: android, icons, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to use the rather smart  [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html) and it is going ok except for 1 rather important thing. The app icon seems to be firmly stuck in the middle of the actionbar.
I am currently deploying on 2.3.4, not using actionbar tabs and using the theme
`android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"`

Everything works fine except for this. I have also tried it on the emulator.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Solved I was stupidly not telling Eclipse that I was designing using android 3.2 or higher.
This messed up the appearance of the actionbar when built.

I also found it essential to build the sherlock library from the downloaded zip file outside my workspace.